# Get system information with Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90, preprocessor

I'm interested in getting system information through Fortran - categories may include:

1. Operating system name
2. Operating system version
3. CPU architecture (32/64-bit)
4. Number of cores

It's my understanding that you can get basic OS information through preprocessing directives, such as

```
#ifdef _WIN32
  print *,'Windows'
#ifdef _APPLE_
  print *,'macOS'
#ifdef __linux
  print *,'Linux'
#endif
```

This is a working solution for category 1, but still leaves 2 - 4.

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably have a look at the intrinsic routines `execute_command_line` and `get_environment_variable`.

Comment: Don't forget 2-4 will differ between Windows and Linux. It is better to ask a single question, because your points may require different means.

Comment: Mark, brilliant idea but I couldn't get it working. Doing something like: `call execute_command_line("export TMP1=$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN)",wait=.true.); call getenv("TMP1",cores)` returns an empty string.

Comment: Vladimir, thanks for pointing that out. When crafting the question, the categories all seemed like subsets of a larger question, but I do understand your point.

Comment: Brilliant indeed but not without 'issues'.  I think the first issue is that the execution of the command in the call to `execute_command_line` happens in a sub-environment (or whatever the heck they are called on your platform) so any settings, such as environment variables, evaporate when the sub-environment finishes running.  So the environment variable is not in the environment that `get_environment_variable` fishes in.  I think the easiest kludge is ...

Comment: ... to have the command line write to a file, e.g. something like `execute_command_line("getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN > nprocs.dat",wait=.true.)` which you later read.

Comment: Call C functions related to that; starting with [uname(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/uname.2.html) and [sysconf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sysconf.3.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you finished point 1 in the way you showed in the question you can go on for the other points.

In POSIX systems (including Linux) you can execute

```
uname -a
```

to get the OS name and version information like

```
Linux meop37 4.4.104-18.44-default #1 SMP Thu Jan 4 08:07:55 UTC 2018 (05a9de6) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

you can store this in a file and read the file Fortran (just redirect stdout).

In Linux you can read `/etc/os-release` to find out the OS version.

In my case it includes:

```
NAME="openSUSE Leap"
VERSION="42.2"
ID=opensuse
...
```

In Linux you can read `/proc/cpuinfo` to get a lot information about the CPU (including those you request). It is your responsibility to parse it somehow in Fortran.

In my case it contains:

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 58
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
stepping        : 9
microcode       : 0x1c
cpu MHz         : 1693.800
cache size      : 8192 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 8
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 4
...
```

I have zero knowledge about MS Windows. Your question is very (too?) broad so I think answering just a part of it is acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

You can kinda do all that stuff in Fortran, except not really. The `COMPILER_VERSION()` string from the `ISO_FORTRAN_ENV` module should provide the name of the OS at least. From that you know what procedures to invoke to get further information.

```
program test
   use ISO_C_BINDING
   use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV
   implicit none
   integer, parameter :: bitness = bit_size(0_C_INTPTR_T)
   write(*,'(*(g0))') 'This is a ',bitness,'-bit system.'
   write(*,'(*(g0))') COMPILER_VERSION()
end program test
```

Here's my output with gfortran:

```
This is a 64-bit system.
GCC version 7.2.0
```

So gfortran isn't very helpful. I consider that to be a bug. ifort doesn't have `COMPILER_VERSION()` at all; maybe that's just because I have old versions of both compilers. Anyway, if you could get the OS from the `COMPILER_VERSION()` string, you would know how to load useful functions like `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` in Windows. Then you create parameters that have the names of the OS procedures you want if you have the right OS and the name of a stub procedure if not.

```
   logical, parameter :: v0 = index(v5,'WINDOWS') /= 0
   character(*), parameter :: v6 = merge('LoadLibraryA','Stub12345678',v0)
   interface
      function LoadLibrary(lpFileName) bind(C,name=v6)
         import
         implicit none
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES STDCALL :: LoadLibrary
!GCC$ ATTRIBUTES STDCALL :: LoadLibrary
         integer(C_INTPTR_T) LoadLibrary
         character(kind=C_CHAR) lpFileName(*)
      end function LoadLibrary
   end interface
```

That way you can access `LoadLibrary` if you're in Windows and not cause an unsatisfied external reference if not. Unfortunately gfortran doesn't think having a named constant rather than a character literal for the binding name is valid.

But in principle you can use the compiler to tell you the OS name and set up a few critical functions you need to beg the OS for the rest of the stuff, but it needs a more advanced compiler than I've got. If you have a better compiler I could edit in more stuff and you could see if it crashes on your end.

Answer (score 0):

I give answer for architecture and detail system information in Windows 10. (maybe it can work in other Windows systems.)

```
program info
implicit none
print*,'detail system information: (on Windows 10)'
call system('SystemInfo')
print*
read(*,*)
print*,'system architecture:'
call system('wmic OS get OSArchitecture')
print*
end program
```

I used help [from](https://superuser.com/questions/96092/how-can-i-determine-if-the-current-version-of-windows-is-either-32-bit-or-64-bit) to obtain  architecture. Generally subroutine `call system(String_variable)` starts up cmd line and get system commands. Similar way it starts up terminal in Ubuntu and get shell commands. (System commands are obviously different for different operation systems.)